# Drive no longer mounts on boot

Tags: boot, server, mount, fstab

I have a server running Ubuntu Server (no GUI) and have a drive mounted to a specific folder using fstab however the other day, following a reboot, it failed to mount and during the start up, I get the following error…

```
An error occurred while mounting /home/user/Media/sdb.
keys:Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I’m fairly new to linux server and learning but I know that skip sends me to my normal user log in and manual takes me in a root.

I’ve checked my fstab file and the disk in question (sdb1) IS present…

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4e17c0d0-4774-4604-b73e-706f213208a3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=ab7d9edb-65cf-45fa-8306-6d26b42099cd /home           xfs     defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f1d67199-1b76-4035-9efe-f87ffcebe4d9 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1       /home/stephen/Media/sdb ext4    defaults        0       0
/dev/md0        /home/stephen/Media/raid1       ext4    defaults        0       0
```

I also tried using the skip option and then manually mounting the drive and this works fine so I’m guessing I’ve screwed up on the fstab side but I’m struggling to identify what’s happened.

I also tried changing the `/dev/sdb1` reference to the UUID instead but this didn’t help.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4e17c0d0-4774-4604-b73e-706f213208a3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=ab7d9edb-65cf-45fa-8306-6d26b42099cd /home           xfs     defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=f1d67199-1b76-4035-9efe-f87ffcebe4d9 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=4C1C25C81C25AE40       /home/stephen/Media/sdb ext4    defaults        0       0
/dev/md0        /home/stephen/Media/raid1       ext4    defaults        0       0
```

Don't have a Windows pc but hooked the drive up to my Mac and managed to get this from diskutil list...

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk3
   1:               Windows_NTFS                         2.0 TB     disk3s1
```

**Output for smartctl -a /dev/sdb**

```
user@user:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green (AF, SATA 6Gb/s)
Device Model:     WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0
Serial Number:    WD-WMAZA5292120
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 0ad758dc6
Firmware Version: 51.0AB51
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 18 20:32:04 2015 BST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (38760) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 374) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   192   192   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       266801
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   175   166   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6250
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2539
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   196   196   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       76
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   056   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       32843
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       139
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       118
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   174   174   000    Old_age   Always       -       78691
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   118   107   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   150   150   000    Old_age   Always       -       50
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   197   197   000    Old_age   Always       -       1061
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   197   197   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1023
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   150   143   000    Old_age   Offline      -       13350

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 8 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 8 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31536 hours (1314 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 d0 75 31 ed  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0d3175d0 = 221345232

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 d0 75 31 ed 08   1d+07:59:43.846  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 c8 75 31 ed 08   1d+07:59:43.846  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 c0 75 31 ed 08   1d+07:59:43.846  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 b8 75 31 ed 08   1d+07:59:43.844  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 b0 75 31 ed 08   1d+07:59:41.951  READ DMA

Error 7 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31511 hours (1312 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 50 fa 94 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0094fa50 = 9763408

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 50 fa 94 e0 08      07:41:58.418  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      07:41:58.415  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      07:41:56.574  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      07:41:55.374  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 6 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31511 hours (1312 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 50 fa 94 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0094fa50 = 9763408

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 50 fa 94 e0 08      07:41:49.814  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 f8 fb 94 e0 08      07:41:49.813  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 f0 fb 94 e0 08      07:41:49.813  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 e8 fb 94 e0 08      07:41:49.812  READ DMA
  c8 00 08 e0 fb 94 e0 08      07:41:49.812  READ DMA

Error 5 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31511 hours (1312 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 50 fa 94 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0094fa50 = 9763408

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 50 fa 94 e0 08      07:41:39.776  READ DMA

Error 4 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31511 hours (1312 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 50 fa 94 e0  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0094fa50 = 9763408

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 08 50 fa 94 e0 08      07:41:18.237  READ DMA
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 08      07:41:18.236  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08      07:41:18.232  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 a0 08      07:41:17.219  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     32842         290392361
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     32841         290392360
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     32841         290392360

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Hope this helps.

If anyone can advise as to where I’m going wrong, I’d be grateful.

Thanks,
Ste

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** That looks like a UID for an NTFS partition.  if so and the drive is external, hook it up to a Windows machine and run `chkdsk X: /F` Where `X` is the drive letter on Windows.  If not NTFS, press [S], [edit] your answer and add the output of `dmesg | tail --lines=25` In both cases, leave a comment @Fabby afterwards.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for your help. Apologies for the slow response. I don't have a Windows PC available at the moment but hooked it up to Mac and ran Distil list in the terminal. I notice it's Windows_NTFS format. Would this cause a problem?  I'll try to take the drive to work tomorrow and get our IT guys to hook it up for me and report back.

Comment: I know nothing about Macs so I couldn't tell you...  If IT doesn't want to help, drop me a note as `freedos` might be able to help too!

Comment: @Fabby Cheers. Appreciate the help. IT guys are aright so I reckon they'll help. I'll come back tomorrow with whatever it turns up. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't thank me!  If it works, come back, I'll post an answer and then you'll be able to [accept it as valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby So I attached the drive to my Windows PC and Windows Explorer (My computer, start menu etc) completely froze. I left it for 20mins+ with no change. Rebooted and tried again with no luck. I am starting to wonder if there is something more seriously wrong with the drive itself. When I plugged it into my Mac it took a good 10-15 mins to be recognized. Is there a possibility this could a corrupt drive issue?

Comment: Can you do a `sudo smartctl --test=short /dev/sdb`  after you press skip and boot in Ubuntu? (I haven't bought anything from Apple since the good Steve left the company, so cannot feed back on that)

Comment: Not used smartctl before. Looks like a great admin tool. Can you tell me where the output for this command will appear? I see that other commands such at smartctl -i etc just print on screen but for the test=short, it appears to run in the background. Thanks.

Comment: Erm, it runs on the disk's processor itself without output...  However, the '--all' that you used, produced the output.  Answer coming up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems that your disk has a read failure:**

```
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     32842         290392361
```

and had a DMA failure 54 days in the past:

```
Error 8 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 31536 hours (1314 days + 0 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
Command/Feature_Name: READ DMA
```

(54 days from the time you ran the `smartctl --test=short /dev/sdb`)

And again a few times the same error one day and one hour before that (Errors 7, 6, 5 and 4)

Unfortunately, I see only one way out of the mess you've got (well, two, but one is commercial and I need to ask around if I'm allowed to post commercial solutions):

**Stop using the disk ASAP, buy another disk larger or equal to your current disk, and use `ddrescue` to copy the good sectors off the bad disk onto the new disk.**

Look around this site how to use `ddrescue`. If it's still unclear after looking around, feel free to [ask another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) referring to the questions that you've looked into already and explain what went wrong!

<sub>Feel free to leave a comment below if you want a commercial solution as well.</sub>

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was starting to look suspiciously like a hardware problem due to the slow read speeds but now I know what I'm looking for in the smartctl report in the future. I think I'll just go for the surefire solution of a new hard drive. Appreciate the guidance.